# Return all Generic List objects that implement an interface

Tags: c#, interface

I'm attempting to return all Animal objects that implement IHerd.

Could someone point me in the direction?

```
public interface IHerd {
        void Herd();
    }

    public class Dog : Animals, IHerd {
        public void Herd() {
            // Swim method
        }
    }

    public class Animals {
        public void Eat() { }
        public void Poop() { }
    }

    public class Farm {
        public List<Animals> FarmAnimals = new List<Animals>();

        public Animals GetHerders() {
            return FarmAnimals.OfType<IHerd>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Animals.OfType<IHerd>().Cast<Animals>().ToList();
```

You also need to change your return type to match

Comment: You don't need the `Cast`.

Comment: Yes you do, because `IHerd` and `Animals` are related only in their sometimes being implemented in the same class, and thus you can't implicitly treat a `List<IHerd>` as a `List<Animals>` because IHerd could be implemented on classes not derived from Animals. If instead of IHerd, a derived class HerdAnimal were implemented, you could avoid the cast if you were using Framework v4.0 which makes Lists covariant.

Answer (score 5):

```
return Animals.OfType<IHerd>().OfType<Animals>()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FarmAnimals.Where(x => x is IHerd)
```